# amp-bind: get weekday from a date

Tags: javascript, date, amp-html

I have an `amp-state` with the current day, month and year.
I would like to find out the weekday.

In 'regular' javascript this can be done using [`Date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).
This does not seem to work in AMP:

```
<amp-state id="currentDate">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "day": 6,
    "month": 6,
    "year": 2006
  }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<span [text]="Date(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day).getDay()">...</span>
```

Which results in:

```
amp-bind: Expression evaluation error in "Date(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day).getDay()". Date is not a supported function.
```

Is there a method of achieving this nonetheless (preferably without the use of an `amp-iframe`)?

Comment: If it did work, it should be `currentDate.month - 1`. ;-)

Comment: I know this isn't the best answer, but have you tried using amp-timeago? https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-timeago - I don't believe date functions are supported with amp-bind yet, but according to this issue it's being considered: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/8040